# android programming: need help creating files inside my app

Tags: java, android

I am creating an android app and am trying to create a program that involves creating a folder file inside my app and being able to save it to any directory.

**I would want it to be created inside my app and it should allow for as many files as the user wants to be created**. How do I do that?

Here is my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Create extends Activity {

    EditText textmsg;
    static final int READ_BLOCK_SIZE = 100;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);

        textmsg=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    }

    // write text to file
    public void WriteBtn(View v) {
        // add-write text into file
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileout=openFileOutput("mytextfile.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
            OutputStreamWriter outputWriter=new OutputStreamWriter(fileout);
            outputWriter.write(textmsg.getText().toString());
            outputWriter.close();

            //display file saved message
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File saved successfully!",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }

    // Read text from file
    public void ReadBtn(View v) {
        //reading text from file
        try {
            FileInputStream fileIn=openFileInput("mytextfile.txt");
            InputStreamReader InputRead= new InputStreamReader(fileIn);

            char[] inputBuffer= new char[READ_BLOCK_SIZE];
            String s="";
            int charRead;

            while ((charRead=InputRead.read(inputBuffer))>0) {
                // char to string conversion
                String readstring=String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer,0,charRead);
                s +=readstring;                 
            }
            InputRead.close();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What about permissions in manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Write:

```
    // write text to file
    public void WriteBtn(View v) {
        // add-write text into file
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileout=openFileOutput("mytextfile.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
            fileout.write((textmsg.getText()).getByte())              
            fileout.close();

            //display file saved message
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File saved successfully!",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
```

Read:

```
    // Read text from file
    public void ReadBtn(View v) {
        //reading text from file
        try {
            FileInputStream fileIn = openFileInput("mytextfile.txt");

            byte[] reader = new byte[fileIn.available()];
            if(fileIn.read(reader) != -1){
             String contentFile = new String[reader];
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), contentFile,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            fileIn.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

It will help you.

Comment: now getting errors when i enter this code. FileOutputStream fileout=openFileOutput("mytextfile.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
            fileout.write((textmsg.getText()).getByte())              
            fileout.close();

Comment: Please check textmsg View. is it null?